# Value of property VPCZoneIdentifier must be of type List of String

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

```js
"wordpressASG": {
      "Type": "AWS::AutoScaling::AutoScalingGroup",
      "Properties": {
        "AvailabilityZones": [
          "ap-southeast-2a",
          "ap-southeast-2b"
        ],
        "VPCZoneIdentifier": [
          {
            "ref": "subnetA"
          },
          {
            "ref": "subnetB"
          }
        ],
        "MinSize": "0",
        "HealthCheckGracePeriod": 300,
        "MaxSize": "0",
        "Cooldown": "300",
        "LaunchTemplate": {
          "LaunchTemplateId": {
            "Ref": "wordpressTemplate"
          },
          "Version": {
            "Fn::GetAtt": [
              "wordpressTemplate",
              "LatestVersionNumber"
            ]
          }
        },
        "MetricsCollection": [
          {
            "Granularity": "1Minute",
            "Metrics": [
              "GroupMinSize",
              "GroupMaxSize"
            ]
          }
        ],
        "TargetGroupARNs": [
          {
            "Ref": "wordpressTG"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Probably not a new question, but all examples are of using a subnet parameter. List needs to be string, but ref Should give strings for this thing. The Subnets are being created in the same script.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear. Could you please clarify what you are trying to do, and what problem you are experiencing? Are you saying that you want to refer to two Subnets created elsewhere in the template, but it is not working for you? What errors are you receiving?

Comment: Aren't intrinsic functions case sensitive? Why would you use `ref`, not `Ref` as everywhere else?

Comment: @Marcin You might have just noticed what i managed to miss, i'm pretty certain that's solved it

Comment: if this is the case I will make an answer for future reference if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was the use `ref` instead of `Ref` when listing subsets in `VPCZoneIdentifier`.

Answer (score 0):

To be honest for your parameter use `List<AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id>` and then just use the value of that rather than trying to use individual subnets in your list.

More parameters: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html

Answer (score 0):

In YAML format

```
VPCZoneIdentifier: !Split [',', !Ref Subnets]
```

Define Subnets as a String parameter and pass in like:

```
ParameterKey=Subnets,ParameterValue=\"subnet-0d...d5,subnet-01...03\"
```